# Открытые запросы VK api с требованием токена

Tags: php, javascript, json, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Друзья! Я не особо опытный разработчик, в php так вообще мало что соображаю, а после нововведений VK api получить фотки с альбомов ВК для вывода на свой сайт через js/jq затруднительно. Вернее, получить то можно, но, сдается мне access token светить нежелательно, а без server side я боюсь его безопасно не передать.

Собственно, вопрос: как передать access token от php к js без его потенциальной видимости для посторонних или как получить json массив с данными фото полностью на php и закинуть его в переменную js на странице?

Answer (score 1):

Стоит поменять логику работы и проксировать запросы через свой сервер. То есть клиент запрашивает какие-то фото, запрос уходит к вам, вы со своего сервера с сервисным ключом доступа делаете запрос к API, получаете ответ и передаете на клиент.

Либо можно добавить на сайте авторизацию через ВК и делать запросы к API через библиотеку openAPI вообще не задействуя бэкенд.